# Retrieving destination coordinates from direction services by distance

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, distance, directions

I need to retrieve a destination's coordinates using the google maps api directions service. I already have the starting point coordinates, however instead of specifying an ending point in coordinates, I wish to retrieve the coordinates by specifying a distance (in km).

So I guess my question is the following: is it possible to retrieve the destination latlong coordinates (based/calculated on the road's distance and not directional/straight line) by specifying a distance (amount in km) with the directions service or perhaps any alternative way?

I have an image illustration, however unfortunately am unable to attach to this question as I do not have enough reputation. If my question is unclear in any way, or you wish to see the illustration then please contact me and I'll send it off.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this as the [request parameters](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters) say that origin and destination parameters are required.

Comment: I believe you are correct. There doesn't seem to be any current method in the api which would allow you to do the following.

Answer (score 0):

I beliave it will help someone.

There is a method to get coordinates in the [google maps library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.computeOffset):

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(fromCoordinates, distanceInMeters, headingInDegrees)
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe you are correct. There doesn't seem to be any current method in the api which would allow you to do the following.

Instead I looped through the coordinates returned from the directions service call, and used a function to calculate the distance between coordinates. However even this was not accurate enough as the coordinates returned also seemed to be aggregated and doesn't return an accurate value/distance when calculating the distances between each coordinate as they are aggregated and therefore each coordinate is not necessary along the road.

To work around the above issue, I ended up adding a click event, and plotted the coordinates along the road myself and then stored them in a local json file which I cache and call using an xmlhttprequest.

Fortunately, for my situation I only need to calculate the distance between point A & B on one individual road, so my alternative won't work in cases when you're using multiple or generic roads/locations. You could instead use the first method described, given that you're happy to live with the aggregated data and an in-accurate calculation.

Below are the functions used to calculate the distances between coordinates and then also the final calculation to find the point & coordinates between the final two points. Please note this code relies on and uses jQuery methods.

**1. Calculate distance (in meters) between two coordinates**

```
function pointDistance( begin, end )
{
    var begin   = { lat: begin[0], long: begin[1] },
        end     = { lat: end[0], long: end[1] };

    // General calculations
    var earthRadius     = 6371, //km
        distanceLat     = (end.lat - begin.lat).toRad(),
        distanceLong    = (end.long - begin.long).toRad();

    // Convert lats to radiants
    begin.lat   = begin.lat.toRad();
    end.lat     = end.lat.toRad();

    // Calculation
    var a = Math.sin(distanceLat / 2) * Math.sin(distanceLat / 2) +
            Math.sin(distanceLong / 2) * Math.sin(distanceLong / 2) * Math.cos(begin.lat) * Math.cos(end.lat);

    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a)); 
    var distance = (earthRadius * c) - 0.000536;

    return (distance * 1000);
}
```

**2. Fetch coordinate of final A-B coordinate (based on percentage remaining). The 'matrix' variable is a json array of coordinates.**

```
function getCoordinates( totalDistance )
{
    var lastPoint   = { lat: null, long: null },
        total       = parseFloat(0),
        position    = { start: null, end: null, distance: 0 };

    $(matrix).each(function()
    {
        if ( lastPoint.lat == null )
        {
            lastPoint = { lat: this[0], long: this[1] };
            return;
        }

        var distance = pointDistance([lastPoint.lat, lastPoint.long], [this[0], this[1]]);
        total = total + distance;

        if ( (total / 1000) >= totalDistance )
        {
            position.start      = new google.maps.LatLng(lastPoint.lat, lastPoint.long);
            position.end        = new google.maps.LatLng(this[0], this[1]);
            position.distance   = total;

            return false;
        }

        lastPoint = { lat: this[0], long: this[1] };
    });

    return position;
}
```

**3. Convert numeric degrees to radians**

```
if ( typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === 'undefined' ) {
    Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
        return this * Math.PI / 180;
    }
}
```

Hope the following helps any one with the same or simular problem. I haven't investigated this as I've had no need to, but, perhaps if you're dealing with google's paid services, they don't aggregate the data returned by the call?

Comment: You marked your answer to your question as correct. Your answer doesn't even address the question asked. In addition, you could have just as easily called <br/> `distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pointA, pointB);`